# In John 17:6 and John 17:27 what name of the Father did Jesus want to "make manifest" and "declare" to his disciples?

Tags: john, names-of-god, onomastics

The question is based of Jesus’ prayer recorded at John Ch. 17 in which he made the following statements in verses 6 and 27:

> KJV John 17:
>
> 6 “I have manifested **thy name** unto the men which thou gavest me
> out of the world: thine they were, and thou gavest them me; and they
> have kept thy word.”
>
> 27 “And I have declared unto them **thy name**, and will declare [it:]
> that the love wherewith thou hast loved me may be in them, and I in
> them.”

Comment: 'Father' ... 'thy name' ... The name in which God is glorified by the Son ... is 'Father'.

Comment: Father is a title or formal address not a name.  Example, my father has a name, Fred.  (1 Samuel 19:2) . . .Jonathan told David: “My father (formal address)  Saul (name) . . ."    (1 Kings 5:3) . . .You well know that David (name) my father (formal address). . .

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> ”I am **YHVH**: **that is my name**: and my glory will I not give to another, neither my praise to graven images.” Isaiah 45:8

Since the God of Yeshua is the same God spoken of in the Hebrew scriptures, then it was YHVH’s (Yahweh’s) name that Yeshua declared.

Comment: And yet John failed to include this?

Comment: @RevelationLad, not to mention that John had already said that Jesus was himself the YHVH, and that the Father had been unknown to mankind until now.

Comment: This is not a name that is contextual with question.  In other words, this is a poor answer because it doesn't say why this name is correct rather than any of the other names of God instead.

Answer (score 3):

My name distinguishes me as an individual from any other individual. A family name distinguishes me from any other family. My personal name distinguishes me within my own family.

Within Deity, the Son is distinct from the Father : the Father is distinct from the Son. I say 'distinct' in that each may be distinguished from the other. Yet is there, within Deity, a perfection of unity whereby both are - in one Divine and Holy Spirit - one.

Jesus taught his disciples to address 'Our Father' together, corporately. And he himself, in humanity, addressed himself to 'Father' as an individual (in humanity). The whole of Jesus' prayer of John chapter seventeen is addressed to *Pater*, Father.

> And he said unto them, When ye pray, say, Our Father which art in heaven, Hallowed be thy name. Luke 11:2.

The Holy Spirit has no name. For he is not prominent and not realised, of himself, for such is He. But it is through Him that one is conscious of the Father. And through him that one is conscious of the Son.

I would suggest that, on certain occasions in the Greek scriptures, prayer is addressed to Deity, as such, that is to Theos, God, which could well be understood as being addressed to the Person, the Holy Spirit.

The one born of Mary in Bethlehem is named. This is a matter of his humanity. And he is known - to us (if we believe) - in that humanity and by that name.

He said :

> No man cometh unto the Father but by me. John 6:44.

Regarding the name of 'Jesus Christ of Nazareth' the apostle tells us

> There is none other name under heaven given among men, whereby we must be saved. Acts 4:12.

It is clear from the apostolic writings - written by those authorised to do so by Jesus Christ himself - that men are to believe on Jesus Christ of Nazareth and that, thus, they shall be brought, by him, to the Father, and be brought in a spiritual way by a Spirit who is holy.

And when they do so, they shall do as he did, on earth, in humanity when he said :

> Abba, Father . .  Mark 14:36 . .  all things are possible unto thee.

For the apostle Paul tells us :

> For ye have not received the spirit of bondage again to fear; but ye have received the Spirit of adoption, whereby we cry, Abba, Father. Romans 8:15.

Brought by Christ, in one Spirit - who is holy - the children born of him cry Abba, Father.

Comment: Thanks for that.   But as most the trap is: the "Father" is not a Name, its a title, why? God will answer; Joh 12:27, 28  Jesus said - Father, save me out of this hour. Nevertheless, this is why I have come to this hour.  Father, glorify YOUR NAME.” Then a voice came out of heaven: “I have glorified it and will glorify it again.” Here God the Father clearly make the point that HE has a "Name" which His reply to Jesus make clear. Then many times in the Bible we have the phrase "In the NAME of The LORD"  & the like, thus once again showing the "LORD" is NOT God's "name" as The LORD HAS a "NAME"!

Comment: [] Added   We also have Jesus words at Matthew 28:19; reffering to the OT texts Jesus taught from- ".Go, therefore, and make disciples of people of all the nations, baptizing them in the NAME OF of the Father ["Jehovah" form the OT] and of the Son ["Jesus" via the Angel] and of the holy spirit [on name],

Answer (score 2):

BDAG provides several ways that the noun "name" (Gr: "onoma") is used Greek depending on its associated words.  When "name" is used of God in combination with a verb (eg, here: "I *revealed* your name" John 17:6) BDAG comments: "Although in the preceding examples the name is often practically inseparable from the being that bears it, this is perhaps even more true of the following cases in which the name appears almost as the representation of the Godhead, as a tangible manifestation of the divine nature" Rev 11:18, John 17:6, 26, 1 John 3:23, Rev 2:13, Acts 9:15.

Thus, I understand the name in John 17:6 & 26 to mean that Jesus, by His life, teaching and ministry etc, has revealed the Father's divine nature, namely His character of loving-kindness and the way He deals with us as shown by Jesus.  Jesus declared, "Whoever has seen me has seen the Father" - see John 14:8-14.

Comment: The son of God has a divine nature and a name, Jesus.  The Father has a divine nature so then he should have a name as the altimate divine person as his son has a name.  Matthew 6:9 “‘Our Father in the heavens, let your name be sanctified (hallowed)."

Comment: True - but what is your point?

Comment: What's the name as in my question? Another example the the phrase "in the name of the LORD" and like phrases. "LORD" cannot be God's name as the phrase says 'the "LORD" has a name?

Comment: As explained above, "name" means the character and nature of the Father, not so much a title because none is used here.

Comment: I would put it the other way around; that the person of that name has this kind of nature and character.  Example the name Nimrrod brings to mind a rebel as with the name Absalom.  The name Jezabel brings to mind a murderious pagan Queen that dominated her husband, Ahab.   True a name holds a reputation to it, but the name tells you who that person is out of all other persons.    It the same with the gods, they all have names, Ra, Adonis, Isis, Nebo, Baal, etc. these name have a nature attached to them so the God of the Jews & Jesus gave himself and name according to Jesus, hence my queastion.

Comment: Dr P. McGowan then what you say is very problmatic as the Bible says not as you say!   At Jo 6:46 we have "Not that any man has seen the Father,..." & at  1 Jo 4:12 it says "No one has seen God at any time."  this must be true & that is not as you say, Jesus is the Father as he has never been seen!!   Penned also by John.

Comment: I did not suggest that anyone had "seen" God (the Father) as John 1:14, 18 etc says.  Many have seen God the Son and it was precisely this that reveals the Father and His character to the world as Jesus says.  "No one has ever seen God [the Father]  It is God the Son who is at the Father's heart who has made him known." John 1:18 ESV.

Comment: Then how does this fit into your Jesus not the Father God?    John 14:9   "Whoever has seen me has seen the Father also.. . ."?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question.  Jesus is not the father - I agree; but Jesus came to reveal the Father, specifically His character as pointed out above.

Comment: The trinity says in short one God in three parts thus Jesus is God or so it is said of John 1:1.   So see Jesus you see God the father re John 14;9.    Or then again if Jesus was with God and God is THREE then "The Word " being with God (Father+Son+H.Spirit) would make four persons in the verse 1 of Joh 1.  The point  is Jesus being "God" does not work as God has NOT been seen and Jesus is said to be God??

Comment: You clearly refuse to understand the teaching of the Trinity because THAT is NOT what the trinity doctrine teaches.  Do not critique a straw man.

Comment: I do not believe in the trinity.

Comment: It is obvious you do not believe the trinity.  However, that is irrelevant to properly critiquing the comments made.  Please be fair and do not satirise, mock or caricature in your comments - be nice.

Answer (score 2):

> I have manifested thy name unto the men which thou gavest me out of the world: thine they were, and thou gavest them me; and they have kept thy word. (John 17:6) [KJV]
>
> And I have declared unto them thy name, and will declare it: that the love wherewith thou hast loved me may be in them, and I in them. (John 17:27)

These are two different claims. In 17:6, Jesus states He manifested the name. Manifested is Ἐφανέρωσά which Thayers says here means [to make known by teaching](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G5319&t=KJV). In 17:27 He states He declared (ἐγνώρισα) the name unto them and will declare (γνωρίσω) it. Declare is [to make known](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G1107&t=KJV).

Certainly there are grounds to debate what "the Name" is and in what language Jesus spoke or may have spoken, and how did Jesus manifest the Father's Name. Yet if one accepts the text as written, then the point of emphasis becomes what Jesus claims He will do. That is, He is going to do something which He has already done. In terms of the Name, the prayer closes such to alert the reader to consider what is about to happen.

After praying Jesus and His disciples cross the Kidron brook and enter the garden where He is arrested. When He is confronted, John (chapter 18) records what Jesus said:

> <sup>4</sup> Jesus therefore, knowing all things that should come upon him, went forth, and said unto them, Whom seek ye?
>   <sup>5</sup> They answered him, Jesus of Nazareth. Jesus saith unto them, **I am he**. And Judas also, which betrayed him, stood with them.
>   <sup>6</sup> As soon then as he had said unto them, **I am he**, they went backward, and fell to the ground.
>
> <sup>7</sup> Then asked he them again, Whom seek ye? And they said, Jesus of Nazareth.
>   <sup>8</sup> Jesus answered, I have told you that **I am he**: if therefore ye seek me, let these go their way:
>   <sup>9</sup> That the saying might be fulfilled, which he spake, Of them which thou gavest me have I lost none.

Twice Jesus said ἐγώ εἰμί, literally, "I am" yet translated as "I am he." John records Jesus had spoken these words earlier: to the woman at the well (4:26); to those in the Temple Treasury (8:24, 28, 58); to the disciples at the Last Supper (13:19).

Apparently, from John's perspective, the name of the Father is ἐγώ εἰμί (I am) as is found in the Greek translation of the Old Testament:

> <sup>13</sup> And Moses said unto God, Behold, when I come unto the children of Israel, and shall say unto them, The God of your fathers hath sent me unto you; and they shall say to me, What is his name? what shall I say unto them?
>   <sup>14</sup> And God said unto Moses, I Am That I Am: and he said, Thus shalt thou say unto the children of Israel, I Am hath sent me unto you. (Exodus 3)
>
> και ειπεν ο θεος προς μωυσην **εγω ειμι ο ων** και ειπεν ουτως ερεις τοις υιοις ισραηλ **ο ων** απεσταλκεν με προς υμας

The expression εγω ειμι ο ων can be parsed as Father, εγω ειμι, and Son, ο ων. So the Name given to Moses is Father and Son, εγω ειμι ο ων. Then Moses was sent by the Son ο ων. John, on the other hand, records Jesus was sent by the Father, εγω ειμι.

This echoes the conclusion of the Prologue:

> No man hath seen God at any time; the only begotten Son, which is in the bosom of the Father, he hath declared him.
>
> θεὸν οὐδεὶς ἑώρακεν πώποτε μονογενὴς θεὸς **ὁ ὢν** εἰς τὸν κόλπον τοῦ πατρὸς ἐκεῖνος ἐξηγήσατο
>
> No one has ever seen God; the only God, THE ONE WHO IS, has himself led out into the bosom of the Father.<sup>`1`</sup>

Note:
1. Robert G. Hall, "*The Reader as Apocalyptist*", *John's Gospel and Intimations of the Apocalyptic*, Eds. Catrin H. Williams and Christopher Rowland, Bloomsbury Publishing, 2103, p. 268

Comment: +1 excellent answer. For the the connexion between εγο ειμι and ο ων in the gospel of John.

Answer (score 2):

The name which Jesus manifested - that is to say, manifested as that not yet manifested before His advent - cannot be those names that were known already in the Old Testament - Yahve, Adonai, El etc. - but this name newly and uniquely manifested is the "Father".

Jesus uniquely and unprecedentedly in history invested humans with authority to become God's children (John 1:12), and thus to have God as Father. More precisely, He is the unique and only Revelator of God whom nobody has seen (John 1:18), and whom nobody can either access without Him (John 14:16) or know without Him (Matthew 11:27); while He Himself knows the Father as He is known by the Latter (John 1:15), thus is equal to Him; in virtue of this equality, He is the only natural and co-eternal Son of the Father, the Latter's co-Creator of the universe. And this natural Son authorises also humans to participate in His and the Father's eternal the divine life, by making them His brothers and sisters by adoption (John 20:17).

Thus, the new name of God, the "Father", denotes a new ontological condition of humanity with reference to its creator God, a new and unprecedented degree of intimacy of humanity with God, for by now, through authorisation of the Son, humans also get access to divine life by becoming partakers of it to the fullest possible way; exactly this intimate partaking of divine life is called sonship, and exactly by virtue of this God is revealed as the "Father" of such "sons" and "daughters".

Answer (score 1):

The immensity of God cannot be reduced to just one word [name]. Or even two words [names]. When you are dealing with the superlative degree of Being that is God, words fail us, yet words have been given to us, in the Bible, to describe aspects of God by means of His various names.

Here's a point that really answers this issue. It’s in Judges chapter 13. Manoah and his wife had a supernatural encounter with One who told them that the barren wife would conceive a son. They invited Him to share a meal with them but he replied, "Even though you detain me, I will not eat any of your food. But if you prepare a burnt offering, offer it to the Lord."

Then Manoah enquired, "What is your name, so that we may honour you when your word comes true?"

Now, this possibly means they would give their future son this One's name. But in those days, knowing a person's name was considered to be a privilege that gave you some authority regarding that person. Names were not broadcast willy-nilly, as on Facebook, with strangers being on first-name terms.

The answer Manoah got is intriguing. "Why do you ask my name? It is beyond understanding." Note that the ancient Hebrew for 'beyond understanding' can be translated as 'Wonderful'. And some of the names / titles for the future Messiah were stated in the OT to be "Wonderful, the Mighty God, the Everlasting Father" etc (Isaiah 9:6).  When Manoah then sacrificed a young goat on an altar, this One ascended heavenwards in the flame that blazed up. Every name attached to God is significant but we will never grasp the enormity of our God this side of glory.  The question we need to concentrate on is not how we pronounce in English ancient words for the One Being of God, but whether we can call this Glorious One, "Abba, Father".

So with John 17: 6 & 27 - Jesus used name [singular] to sum up the nature and being of God. Who God is, what he stands for, and the honour of his glorious name.

http://www.prageruniversity.com/Religion-Philosophy/Do-Not-Misuse-Gods-Name.html#.VIih7ovqD3E

Comment: Manoah spoke  to an "angel" (Jug. 13:18) the angel refused to give his name so as not to ditract from Jehovah. A lot in a "Name:" Ex 3:14-15 So God said to Moses: “I Will Become What I Choose to Become.” And he added: “This is what you are to say to the Israelites, ‘I Will Become has sent me to you.’” Then God said once more to Moses:“This is what you are to say to the Israelites, ‘Jehovah the God of your forefathers, the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob, has sent me to you.’ This is my name forever, and this is how I am to be remembered from generation to generation."NWT

Comment: Yes, I appreciate that, ethos. I'm hoping the episode in Judges chapter 13 might open up your understanding to how any heavenly name is not about pronouncing syllables in human language, but of grasping the enormity of who it belongs to. Humans like to know names, to use them, but God's names are so significant that no one single word can encapsulate all that God is. Yet Jesus encapsulates this more than any words can, being "the radiance of God's glory and the exact representation of his Being" Hebrews 1:1-4, having "the name that is above every name" Philippians 2:9.

Comment: Ture; but then why did God put his name (JHVH) in The Scriptures about  7,000 times, more than any other name in the Bible; if he did not want it 1) to stand out, 2) be used?   Ezekiel 38:23  "And I will certainly magnify myself and sanctify myself and make myself known before the eyes of many nations; and they WILL HAVE TO KNOW that I am Jehovah.’"

Comment: You are now asking another question that looks suspiciously as though you have asked the first question in order to promote your own personal understanding of the matter. It seems as if you are out to tell readers that Jesus wanted to make known YHWH (in those verses you quote, even though Jesus nowhere spoke of YHWH.) If you are so sure, why did you ask us a question? I am not here to get into an argument with you. I answered your question but if you don't like it, you can ignore it. I will not be baited into an argument designed to let you promote your own answer, thanks all the same.

Comment: Its in the Bible see Psalm 83:18 & Ex. 6:3  KJV. Thus how is it MY idea when it is in Scripture?   The New English Bible: 
The name Jehovah appears at Exodus 3:15; 6:3. 

See also in Genesis 22:14; Exodus 17:15; Judges 6:24; Ezekiel 48:35. 


If this and other translations use “Jehovah” in several places, why not be consistent in using it at every place where the Tetragrammaton appears in the Hebrew text?

Comment: Nobody is denying that YHWH is in the OT a huge number of times. That, however, is not the point of your question but it appears that you are trying to turn your question into an opportunity to promote one particular English transliteration of the Tetragrammaton.  I have answered your question by referring you to Judges chapter 13 with regard to the significance of what a divine name represents. That is all I wish to contribute, for your consideration and edification, thank you.

Comment: Many Many translations use YHWH / JHVH etc. etc. I0's of thousads Jewish texts and Bibles do also.  Go to  https://www.nehemiaswall.com/  A good one to look at is the DNKJB here http://www.dnkjb.net/     Regards ethos

Comment: It is part of the question as Jesus ONLY the OT to teach.

Answer (score 1):

If Jesus were trying to make the name/title "YHVH" be "manifest" and "declared" to his disciples then he failed miserably since he is never recorded mentioning it so it isn't in any of his recorded sayings.

Perhaps what we are seeing today is the inverse of what happened here:

> KJV Exodus 6:3 And I appeared unto Abraham, unto Isaac, and unto Jacob, by the name of God Almighty, **but by my name JEHOVAH was I not known to them**.

In other words, to the Jews he revealed himself and related to the Jews "by the name" or "I, after some time, chose to reveal myself to the Jews by the covenant name of YHVH". Maybe?

The more "critical" approach to the problem of the abandonment of the name is simply that:

- out of concern of taking God's name in vain the Jews had an aversion to the use of the name except during worship
- a large concentration of Jews in Alexandria, Egypt in North Africa became hellenized and dependent on a Greek translation of the Hebrew scriptures (the LXX) which opted to translate the Tetragrammaton as "hO KURIOS"
- the writers of the NT were hellenized Jews so they used hO KURIOS as well

Perhaps it is both:

- God oversaw the disuse of the name because it fit his plan
- God intended to not "reveal" himself to the Body of Christ by the name he used for Israel and used the disuse to that end

So what name/title did Jesus declare? Well, "Our Father who is in the sky" or just "Our Father" or "Father", etc. Not "Elohim" or "El" or "YHVH" though. It appears the "name" he declared and made manifest ("seen") was "the Father of Israel":

> KJV Exodus 4:22 And thou shalt say unto Pharaoh, Thus saith the LORD, **Israel is my son, even my firstborn**:

Paul, coming **after** Jesus and sent to **the gentiles** often used variations of "the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ".

Comment: Good thoughts the Bible goes on to say: DNKJB Ex. 3:15 And God said moreover unto Moses,Thus shalt thou say unto the children of Israel, JEHOVAH the God of your fathers, the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob hath sent me unto you: THIS IS MY NAME FOR EVER, and this is my memorial unto ALL GENERATIONS. - KJV Psalm 83:16-18  Fill their faces with shame; that they may seek THY NAME, O LORD. Let them be confounded and troubled for ever yea, let them be put to shame, and perish:That [men] may know that THOU WHOSE NAME alone [is] JEHOVAH, [art] the most high over all the earth.

Comment: Scientists tell us that if you shot an arrow from where ever you are on earth and it escaped earth's gravity it would travel on forever and never hit anything. The chance that your arrow would hit an object in space is much less unlikely than you winning the lottery. Space is so huge. So your arrow would travel on forever. As you probably already know, the Hebrew "forever" is not necessarily "forever" as in English. "OLAM", like "AIWN" has the sense of that arrow flying until it hits something, like the END of the age. "ALL generations" refers to all generation of the Jews, now cut off.

Comment: So why say "for ever."?   Micah 4:5  For all the peoples will walk, each in the name of its god, But we will walk in the name of Jehovah (Heb. "JHVH") our God FPREVER AND EVER.!!!   See Matthew 6:9; What did Jesue say as a pratcing JEW?
[] Added
Ezekiel 36:23  ‘I will certainly sanctify MY GREAT NAME, which was profaned among the nations [NON JEWS], which you profaned among them; and the nations [NON JEWS]  WILL HAVE TO KNOW that I am Jehovah (Heb. "JHVH"),’ declares the Sovereign Lord Jehovah  (Heb. "JHVH") , ‘when I am sanctified among you before their eyes.
Into the future

Comment: The Jews forfeited their distinction as God's "People" when they refused their king and killed his prophets. And, if I'm correct, then God's covenant name disappeared into history as well, ultimately by God's sovereign design.

Comment: *“Paul, coming after Jesus and sent to the gentiles often used variations of the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ”* This is an argument Marcion made. He believed the God of the OT was evil, and that Jesus- through his “apostle” Paul, came to reveal the “real god”... Matthew 24:23-25. How did Yeshua fail when you, ethos, and I know God’s real name? We might disagree how to *pronounce* or *spell* his name- but we all know his name is YHVH... YeHoVaH or YaHVeH.

Comment: As did the patriarchs of old. However, in Exodus a special decision to use that name in relations with them was made. So the casual use of the name is different from the covenant use: Exodus 15:3 "The LORD is a man of war: the LORD is his name." IE: The name suggests all that God will be to those who keep his covenant AND suggests what he will do to those who are not part of that covenant if they mess with the covenant People. We this when God puts his name in the angel.

Comment: @Ruminaror  Very True.  That is why the Christians picked up were the Jews left of: [] Added  Acts 15:13, 14  ".After they finished speaking, James replied: “Men, brothers, hear me. 14 Symʹe·on has related thoroughly how God [OF THE JEWS] for the first time turned his attention to the nations [NON JEWS]  to take out of them A PEOPLE FOR HIS NAME   ["JHVH"].  &  1 Peter 2:10  "For you were once not a people, but now you are God’s ["JHVH"] people; once you had not been shown mercy, but now you have received mercy.

Comment: James is probably referring to the name given to believers at Antioch: "Christians": KJV Acts 11:20 "And when he had found him, he brought him unto Antioch. And it came to pass, that a whole year they assembled themselves with the church (τῇ ἐκκλησίᾳ), and taught much people. And the disciples were called (Χριστιανούς) Christians first in Antioch." Possibly "the Assembly" but more likely "Christians". See Isaiah 62:2 "And the Gentiles shall see thy righteousness, and all kings thy glory: **and thou shalt be called by a new name, which the mouth of the LORD shall name.**"

Comment: Perhaps relevant: KJV Revelation 3:12 "Him that overcometh will I make a pillar in the temple of my God, and he shall go no more out: and I will write upon him the name of my God, and the name of the city of my God, which is new Jerusalem, which cometh down out of heaven from my God: **and I will write upon him my new name.**"

Comment: @Ruminator The Hebrews knew YHVH’s name, but they didn’t understand what it means. They somehow got the idea that “to be” should mean “I am” and created some Hellenized Greek god. God said “I cause to be what I cause to be”. YHVH prepared an image of himself when he made Adam, and Adam’s son Yeshua is the perfect accomplishment of that image. Yeshua declared God’s name because Yeshua means “YHVH salvation”. So to believe in “Yeshua” is to believe that “HE will cause salvation” or “HE will deliver us from harm”.

Comment: The word "Yeshua" does not appear in the NT. The name used in the NT is the Greek name, "Jesus", not the Hebrew name "Yeshua" (nor, "Yehoshuah"). And by the way, Jesus lived one generation before the end of the Jewish age ergo it is fitting that he have that connection. It is irrelevant now (in terms of the covenant name).

Comment: @Ruminator "Yeshua" appers in the Hebrew NT and so does "Yahweh" as they both do in the OT and so as Jesus taught people to worship the God of the OT the Hebrew NT seems much more accurate!

Comment: @Ruminator If Yeshua does not appear in the NT, then who is Stephen talking about in Acts 7:45? If “Jesus” means “Yeshua”, then Jesus means YHVH salvation- so it doesn’t seem to make much difference. Yeshua, Yehoshua, Iesous, Joshua... our cultural pronunciations don’t matter- all that matters is what it means.

Comment: If it doesn't matter, then why do want to call him by a name other than the one used consistently in the NT? By faith I understand that the name in the NT is the name God intended to be in the NT and the one I should use. IE: "If it was good enough for Paul then it's good enough for me".

Comment: So do you "correct" NT quotations of the OT to match the OT? Or just the name?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [user26950's comments](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/35179/in-john-176-and-john-1727-what-name-of-the-father-did-jesus-want-to-make-mani/53875#comment70111_35526):

> ... But as most the trap is: the "Father" is not a Name, its a title, why? God will answer; Joh 12:27, 28 Jesus said - Father, save me out of this hour. Nevertheless, this is why I have come to this hour.  Father, glorify YOUR NAME.” Then a voice came out of heaven: “I have glorified it and will glorify it again.” Here God the Father clearly make the point that HE has a "Name" which His reply to Jesus make clear. Then many times in the Bible we have the phrase "In the NAME of The LORD" & the like, thus once again showing the "LORD" is NOT God's "name" as The LORD HAS a "NAME"!

> [] Added We also have Jesus words at Matthew 28:19; reffering to the OT texts Jesus taught from- ".Go, therefore, and make disciples of people of all the nations, baptizing them in the NAME OF of the Father ["Jehovah" form the OT] and of the Son ["Jesus" via the Angel] and of the holy spirit [on name]

But I would like to add this.

When Yeshua said

> 28 Πάτερ δόξασόν σου τὸ ὄνομα Ἦλθεν οὖν φωνὴ ἐκ τοῦ οὐρανοῦ Καὶ ἐδόξασα καὶ πάλιν δοξάσω”

Translated:

> "Glorify of you, the Name!" Came then a voice from the heavens, 'And (I have) esteemed glorious and (will) further esteem gloriously (The Name)!'

Who or What is The Name of God?

Isaiah 30 from Scroll 1Q Isaiah a

> 27 Behold, Yahweh’s name comes from far away, burning with his anger, and in thick rising smoke. His lips are full of indignation, and his tongue is as a devouring fire. 28 His breath is as an overflowing stream that reaches even to the neck, to sift the nations with the sieve of destruction; and a bridle that leads to ruin will be in the jaws of the peoples.

Isaiah 30 from Scroll 1Q Isaiah b

> 27 Behold, Yahweh’s Name comes from far away, burning with his anger, and in thick rising smoke. His lips are full of indignation, and his tongue is as a devouring fire.

The Name of God is a Messenger. See Exodus 20:24, Exodus 33:19, Nehemiah 1:9, Jeremiah 44:26, Nehemiah 1:7-9.

David drew up the plans for the Temple of God (the "House for My Name") and his son Solomon built it.

Now, in Revelation of John, Yeshua comes with judgment.

Revelation 8:7

> The first sounded, and there came hail and fire, mixed with blood, and they were thrown to the earth; and a third of the earth was burned up, and a third of the trees were burned up, and all the green grass was burned up.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for this well-considered answer.  Please take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

"The Lord our God is one" this is a deep subject that is not near as important to understand ...as it is " To keep our lamps full of oil.
I would add to the discussion this though.... The 2 titles (Father Son) and the "Holy Spirit" Who is in fact the presence, guidance,  are the  2 rolled into 1 as the Spirit of God "WE will make our home in you" is the answer to the name ,within the name of Jesus.... the name JESUS "Yeshua" ( Yhwh saves) with Jesus name both prophesied in the old testament and revealed in Mary's revelation "Emanuel" (God with us) ……..indicates God is with us, to save us?. The 3 in one is for men to dispute and to discuss to satisfy their "OWN" satisfaction, not Gods.
The more important question other than understanding, the  When where what and who is God and His name, can take us away from the more important question...…
What are we doing with the talents that God has given us to perform, the 3 duties when "Led by His Spirit"   …." Preach the gospel" "Make disciples" " Teach them the things that He has taught us (Learn from me). These are what God will use each of us for,  to both help us and those who receive.
Questions about matters that are Gods, are for Greek philosophers, we could argue the point from know till He returns and still not be satisfied.

Paul emphasis on knowing Christ, through "Offering ourselves as living sacrifices" was at the very centre of what he both practised and taught , and would be disappointed in how the Religious systems of today think? 
In His mind, he had know doubt as to who and what Jesus was "The fullness of the Godhead bodily". He understood Jesus own words...……. "I never knew you" Blessing to all.

Comment: Hello mark, welcome to BHSE, glad to have you with us. If you haven't already, please make sure to take our tour, to see how we are a little different from other sites you may know. Thanks! (hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Baptize in The Name of The Father, The Son and The Holy Spirit,

Yehoshua/Yeshua
The Apostles understood the Name of which represented the triune God and why they baptized in water by the Name Yehoshua/Yeshua/Iesous which means Savior/Salvation

There is no Savior but YHVH
Isaiah 43:11

Even though Yehoshua/Yeshua is a popular name amongst the Hebrew people This Name is what was made known to us by the Name of the Son in representing the Father, Father being in Him and Him in the Father.

Acts 4:12
And there is salvation in no other, for there is not another name under heaven having been given among men, by which it behooves us to be saved."

So the 1 Name given to the Son is the Name of the Father but also the Spirit as YHVH alone is our salvation.

Comment: The Trinity are all God, one substance. When you say "Son given the Name of the Father" do you have a verse in mind? "I and the Father are one" speaks of separate names and personalities but in total agreement, I suggest.

Comment: The Name YAHVH Is the triunes proper Name But the Son incarnate was given the name Yeshua by Father presented by Gabriel which is a shortened form of Yehoshua which means YAHVH is salvation This name Yeshua meaning salvation represents the Triunity in that there is no Savior but YAHVH as Father was revealing His salvation to the nations psalm 98:2 #3444so the only name givenunder heaven that which one can besaved by calling upon Is thesingle Nameof the Father, the Son andthe Spirit that we are baptized in being Yeshua. The Apostles understood this aswhy they baptized in the Name of the Yeshua.

Answer (score 0):

The name YHWH. The divine name of his Father and his God is YHWH. There is no other God in the scriptures that is named YHWH. The English bible is translated from Hebrew, Greek and Aramaic languages. If one would say that YHWH does not appear in the New Testament, consider Luke 4:17-21 of the Aramaic Bible in Plain English says, And the scroll of Isaiah the Prophet was given to him and Yeshua opened the scroll and he found the place where it is written “The Spirit of THE LORD JEHOVAH is upon me, and because of this he has anointed me to preach The Good News to the poor; he has sent me to heal broken hearts and to proclaim liberty to captives, vision to the blind, and to restore the crushed with forgiveness,” “And to proclaim the acceptable era of THE LORD JEHOVAH" And he rolled up the scroll and he gave it to the minister and he went and sat down, but all who were in the synagogue fixed their eyes upon him.

Now let us look at verse he quoted from Isaiah, Isaiah 61:1 of the Young's Literal Translation Bible says, The Spirit of the Lord Jehovah is on me, Because Jehovah did anoint me To proclaim tidings to the humble, He sent me to bind the broken of heart, To proclaim to captives liberty, And to bound ones an opening of bands.According to this verses, who did YHWH sent? His son, Jesus Christ, John 17:3. This is why Jesus instructed us to pray "hallowed be thy name". Matthew 6:9.

Answer (score -1):

Re : The question was asked quote: " In John 17:6 what name to make manifest and declare to his disciples."
Answer : " Jesus."
The name to be made manifest  and declared is "Jesus".
References: 
MATTHEW  chapter 1 verse 21 says quote " And she shall bring forth a son ,and thou shalt call his name JESUS: for he shall save his people from their sins".
JOHN  chapter 20 verse 31 says quote "But these are written, that he might believe that Jesus is the Christ ,the Son of God ; and that believing ye might have life though his name "
"It ain't 'rocket science".
However to Nicodemus it was and in today's world it still is for many people.Sadly.
Read JOHN  chapter 3 ,verses 1 to 21.
Here the lights were on but nobody was home.
However we do know from scripture that he did   became a follower. 
User 32276 Dennis

Answer (score -1):

The name of our father in Heaven, the name of the father of the race of men the federal head of the race, the name of the father of Jesus is ADAM. For Jesus is ABEL reborn the kinsman-redeemer of his father.  Redeem Adam and you redeem all his children.

Comment: Hi Terry, welcome to BH-Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here. Please be sure to take the [site tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read our [code of conduct](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/conduct). Thanks!

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.